# Webview. Is it program error or android issue?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I have an app built around Webview. It has three elements, one a direct link to a website the other two link to  internal html files containing java script. The app has been downloaded over 1000 times over the last 2 years without a problem until recently a client reported the internal links threw up "File does not exist or cannot be opened" error.
He reported that the app worked previously on his lenovo device but after a failed upgrade and subsequent factory reset produced the error. Reinstall didn't work.
Is it program error or android issue? Is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Yes I came to read that now webview got some authentication issue in loading https pages in latest releases especially when we use onReceivedError() method in it and handle some issue. But I am not 100% sure of it as I havent got this issue. So while using webview properly handle SSl certificate. This issue is occurring only in latest releases. This may fix your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I'm aware of the  security issue  but that's  not

Comment: Are you handling anything in onReceivedError()?

Comment: No. No need as there is no link to any https site. All links are internal. All assets are contained in /resources/www. As I say the app has worked perfectly for many years and I recently installed it on another device without any problem. I'm beginning to think it's just a problem with an individual device